# How to communicate with python server from web browser?

Tags: javascript, python, server, client, communication

I'm trying to send basic commands to a robot from a webbrowser.
The robot is connected to my network and it is running a simpleXMLRPC server as below:

```
import socket
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer

message = []

def py_setMsg(msg):
    #global message
    message.append(msg)
    return "check"
    
def py_getMsg():
    if len(message) > 0:
        temp = str(message[-1])
        message.pop(-1) 
        return temp
    else:
        return "(no message)"

hostname = socket.gethostname()
host = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
port = 60050
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer((host, port))
server.register_function(py_setMsg, "ext_setMsg")
server.register_function(py_getMsg, "ext_getMsg")
print("XMLRPC Server started..")
server.serve_forever()
```

My robot checks the messages in the message list and executes the commands in the list one by one.
What I want is to be able to add these commands from a web browser. So basically I want a command to be added to the list in my python server when a button is pressed, something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="setMessage()">klik hier</button>
    <script>
    function setMessage(){
        send command to my python server
    }   
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: You have to connect to the RPC host in js when the button is clicked then call whatever the function you want , what exactly do you face difficulties with ?

Comment: may be create html form which takes input(text box ,if predefined commands then drop down option can be used) and the click on submit button

Comment: The thing I have difficulties with is calling a function in my python script from my javascript file. On the robot side I do this via the xmlrpc library from node.js. However on the browser side I'm not able to use this. So I don't know how to connect to the RPC host in javascript and call one of its function.